# dynamic variable in ng-repeat Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ngtable

My aim is to have a flexible number of tables and the tables being themselves dynamic.

This is my html code so far.

```
<div ng-repeat="deviceType in vm.devicesType">
<h2 ng-click="collapse=!collapse">My {{deviceType}}s <Strong ng-show="collapse">-</Strong><Strong ng-show="!collapse">+</Strong></h2>
<div ng-show="collapse">
<table ng-table-dynamic="user.controller.js.TableParams(deviceType) with user.controller.js.Columns(deviceType)">
    <tr ng-repeat="device in (deviceType)" ng-if="$index==0">
        <th ng-repeat="(key,value) in device" >
            {{key}}
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="device in (deviceType)")>
        <td ng-repeat="(key,value) in device">
            {{value}}
        </td>
        <td>
            <a ng-click="vm.GetDeviceDetails(relay.id)">Details</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

The javascript is not the issue as the variables are well evaluated, however for now my output is an array with R e l a y ( in seperate rows ), Relay being a device type. 
I would like to have the variable (deviceType) evaluated, when I replace with Relay, I have no issues.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you fix it? If so, please help me through it as I am facing the same issue.

Comment: No sorry, I had to start giving some fixed imputs...